# Pass argument to array of functions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, lambda

I have a 2D numpy array of lambda functions. Each function has 2 arguments and returns a float.

What's the best way to pass the same 2 arguments to all of these functions and get a numpy array of answers out?

I've tried something like:

```
np.reshape(np.fromiter((fn(1,2) for fn in np.nditer(J,order='K',flags=["refs_ok"])),dtype = float),J.shape)
```

to evaluate each function in `J` with arguments `(1,2)` ( `J` contains the functions).

But it seems very round the houses, and also doesn't quite work...
Is there a good way to do this?

```
A = J(1,2)
```

doesn't work!

Comment: Why is this an array?  Why not a list (or list of lists)?  It has to be an object dtype array anyways, so you can't do much math on it.  And iteration on a list is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
A = np.asarray([[f(1,2) for f in row] for row in J])
```

This should work for both numpy arrays and list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really clean way, but this is reasonably clean and works:

```
import operator
import numpy as np

# create array of lambdas
a = np.array([[lambda x, y, i=i, j=j: x**i + y**j for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)])

# apply arguments 2 and 3 to all of them
np.vectorize(operator.methodcaller('__call__', 2, 3))(a)
# array([[ 2,  3,  5,  9],
#        [ 4,  5,  7, 11],
#        [10, 11, 13, 17],
#        [28, 29, 31, 35]])
```

Alternatively, and slightly more flexible:

```
from types import FunctionType

np.vectorize(FunctionType.__call__)(a, 2, 3)
# array([[ 2,  3,  5,  9],
#        [ 4,  5,  7, 11],
#        [10, 11, 13, 17],
#        [28, 29, 31, 35]])
```

Comment: Here `vectorize` makes iteration over the 2d `a` easier, but does not improved speed (compared to an explicit loop).